Shaking pencil's hyperbola formula?
When you typically shake a pencil, it bends and forms a curve (hyperbola?). I want to formalize this phenomenon, but I'm not sure how to do it. I'd like to incorporate factors such as amplitude, pencil length, grip position, and angle. Any advice on how to formalize this?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What you want to describe is the envelope of the positions of the pencil, since that is what forms the hyperbola shape.
One simple model: at time $t$ the point where your fingers hold the pencil has position $(0, A \sin(\omega t))$, and the pencil makes an angle $\theta(t)$. The equation for the line of the pencil will be $y(t)=\tan(\theta(t))x + A \sin(\omega t)$. Now you need to (1) find how $\theta(t)$ changes, and (2) find the envelope to the family of curves.
(1) is the physics problem, while (2) is pretty straightforward given the equations on the envelope Wikipedia page. To solve (1) you need to model the kinematics of the pencil: how is it moving? Presumably we have a steady state where energy moves between kinetic energy and potential energy (some kind of spring action in your finger shape).
Example: A simple case where we just assume $\theta(t)=-a\omega t$ (that is, the pen moves down when the fingers move up, at the same angular velocity) gives an equation for the family as $y(t)=\tan(-a\omega t)x + A \sin(\omega t)$. This can be rewritten as $F(t,x,y)=\tan(-a\omega t)x + A \sin(\omega t)-y=0$, and the condition for a point being on the envelope is $\partial F(t,x,y)/\partial t=0$ and $F(t,x,y)=0$. Hence we get the condition $\omega (A\cos(\omega t)-ax \sec^2(a \omega t))=0$ which can be solved for $x=(A/a)\cos(\omega t)\cos^2(a\omega t)$. This can be substituted into $F(t,x,y)$ to get a trigonometric mess that can be plotted. I suspect there is a clever substitution here for one of the trig functions that actually turns it into a nice quadratic formula, but that might require special conditions on $a$.

Very thank you, you gave me about how to approach the problem , really thank you.... I will do try!!!
